# How spontaneously can a spacecraft be deorbited

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, reentry, dragon-v2

Currently the return of AX-1 has been rescheduled multiple days due to weather concerns in the landing area. How quickly could astronauts on the ISS evacuate to the ground if so required?

Scenarios which might create this requirement:

- The littering of the orbit with debris from a general Kessler syndrome
- the break up of the ISS
- an Anti Satellite Test
- the orbit becoming uninhabitable from a Testshot Starfish-like nuclear test or a big solar flare
- a medical emergency
- or the threat of military attack on the ISS.

**Note:** This question has been marked as a duplicate of [How fast can the crew evacuate the ISS? (ACRV)](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5771/how-fast-can-the-crew-evacuate-the-iss-acrv), but it is not. My question is primarily concerned with the deorbit and reentry capability of vessels and its sensitivity to weather. The other question seems to be primarily concerned with leaving the ISS to orbit and undocking preparations.

Comment: If you disagree with the reception of a question, the correct answer is *not* to copy&paste the question (why would you expect a character-for-character identical copy of the question to be received any differently than the original anyway?) but to edit the question to sufficiently distinguish it from the proposed duplicate and convince community members to reopen the question. All that you have achieved now is that your second question is a duplicate of the first question.

Comment: If your question "... is primarily concerned with the deorbit and reentry capability of vessels and its sensitivity to weather" it's odd that it does not mention any of that. Try editing the original question to focus on what you really care about.

Comment: There was a note at the top of the old question saying `Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.` Since it did not resolve the question I asked a new one, going into more detail of how the question was different from the other one.

Comment: Also this question has been marked as a du-locate again but I strongly disagree. It does not concern leaving the ISS but leaving LEO and weather concerns. These are totally different scenarios, and the other question talks about spacecraft availability not reentry zone availability.