# What systems or technologies are developed to protect ISS from space debris?

Tags: iss, debris, safety

What kind of systems or technology is developed for ISS (International Space Station)? There are so many debris at higher orbits than ISS, but many of them has started deorbiting so we have a potential risk that some debris could collide with ISS. Illustrating even with examples is ok, such as different damages suffered before by the ISS and which technology served as protection or solution for these sittuations. Another element that has to do with safety is the evacuating process how fast could be done that?

Comment: What does "safe enough" actually mean for you? It all comes down to the chance of incident you are willing to tolerate. So what level of safety are you asking about?

Comment: @BSteinhurst what kind of materials and protection they have for ISS, had before damages that could cause serious problems to the ISS (coommand systems),what size of debris it can handle and that could be repaired, which parts of the ISS are secured more and that could serve as a life boat. I am not speaking for catastrophic failures, but sometimes something could be broken, could cause small explosions in some segments or depressurize them. How would the ISS avoid the larger space debris and what plans are for these upcoming debris from higher orbits in the next years.

Comment: @BSteinhurst at a scenario that ISS is damaged and loosing height how fast could be evacuated the crew. How much time is needed in an emergency evacuation?

Comment: To answer all the questions raised in your comments would be too long for answers here, they are meant to be no longer than about a page. You could consider asking follow up questions. I think what was meant was more that it would be clearer to ask how safe the station is, rather than if it is safe enough, which depends on opinion.

Comment: For instance, 'What kind of damages has the ISS suffered from debris' could be a separate question - in fact really ought to be as a proper answer would be a few paragraphs.

Comment: @kimholder these comments i put for BSteinhurst to make clear what i was searching for. I was wondering for potential debris that could make ISS facing problems thats why i asked if it is safe enough. But i like your suggestion and i am considering it. I will edit and change some parts of my question

Comment: @J.Young, Kim Holder was correct in closing this question, for two reasons. (1) An ideal question for the SE network requires an answer that is longer than "Yes" or "No" but is significantly shorter than a book. You've asked us to write a book. A question that requires an answer that is handful of paragraphs long is ideal. (2) An ideal question also will have an answer that is demonstrably better than all others. Opinionated questions get in the way of this, and your use of "safe enough" makes your question opinionated.

Comment: Wait - i hadn't looked around, either. There are actually several good answers that address the parts of your question. In addition to the one i listed, there is also [Are there any safety procedures in place on the ISS in case of puncture?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/881/4660). If you look at the sidebar on the right, several others related to this are also listed.

Comment: But now you have some editing practice, and if you continue to look around you will learn more about how to ask good questions, and how to find answers that already exist. :)

Comment: @kimholder ok it looks I haven't done the homework. Didn't search to much for ISS. These questions have explained very good what i was asking for. Thanks Kim for your help