# What would astronauts do in the unlikely event an hole appeared on the side of their spacecraft?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, spacecraft

This never really happened in the Apollo missions, or any other rocket launch... but what would theoretically happen if something exploded (let's say, the oxygen tanks) and caused a hole in the side of the spacecraft?

Would the crew be sucked out  and killed instantly, similar to an airplane, or would the spacecraft automatically try to correct the error and seal the hole?

Also, in the unlikely chance that a hole appears on the side of a spacecraft, what is the normal NASA procedure?

Comment: Depends on how big the hole is. Except fot automatic sealing and correcting, nothing does that.

Comment: @OrganicMarble So if there is a large enough hole on the side of the spacecraft, all the astronauts are goners?

Comment: For a big enough value of large, yes, unless they were already suited up for some reason.

Comment: Shuttle and station have leak procedures but they are for tiny holes. I'm not able to write up an answer now but this may have been asked already.

Comment: There's a [very similar question here](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/881/are-there-any-safety-procedures-in-place-on-the-iss-in-case-of-puncture) including some checks (provided the leak is slow of course)

Comment: Also there was a well-known case of rapid depressurisation leading to the death of all three crew - [Soyuz 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_11). (I think this case has been mentioned in a few other questions in the past.)

Comment: *"what would theoretically happen if something exploded (let's say, the oxygen tanks) and caused a hole in the side of the spacecraft?"* The obvious **case study: Apollo 13**

Comment: FWIW, I disagree with the mod closure of this question as a duplicate of [Are there any safety procedures in place on the ISS in case of puncture?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/881/415) as this question is clearly not only about the ISS, and it's a matter of terminology whether one can consider the ISS a *spacecraft* proper.